# Chrome + Raphael + -webkit-tap-highlight-color = black color

Tags: google-chrome, svg, raphael

I use Raphael on the site.
Today woke up one morning and my svg-logo was repainted in black. Chrome adds to my logo

```
style = "-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
```

How to overcome it? Here you can see how it looks:
http://www.millidream.ru
Thanks!
P.S. now look at another computer - everything is fine, but on my PC I have black logo..

Comment: anyone have any ideas on this subject, how to remove 
style = "-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
and why did this happen? If it came from me, it is possible that other devices will manifest this problem..

Comment: Now, the problem appeared on a different computer! Logo is also painted in black! Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand why. I had to do something like this:

```
<a id="logo" xlink:href="o-nas.php" title=""></a>
```

I read in the documentation:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#AElement
Thanks!

Comment: That's for inside SVG; the `a` tag when used in HTML shouldn't be `xlink:href` but just `href`.

Comment: ok, I know it, but if I use just <a href, without xlink: , my logo is painted in black in Chrome..
that's the problem.

Comment: For example, in the page:
http://www.millidream.ru/bonbonierki.php
I wrote just `href` and what color of logo you see, tell me please?
I have black, you probably white, but over time it becomes black again on another PC..

Comment: here to discuss this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=105357